# Rails way user conversations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to build app with user messages (dialogs).
I've solved this problem by this way:

**app/models/conversation.rb**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :interlocutor
  has_many :messages
end
```

**app/models/message.rb**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :message
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def conversations
    Conversation.uniq.joins(:messages)
      .where("conversations.user_id = ?", self.id)
      .where("conversations.interlocutor_id = ?", self.id)
      .order("messages.created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

I'm confused by **conversations method**. It's like PHP way - no flexibility.

Can it be rewrited by rails way? Maybe it can be AR relationship?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [scoping](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/02/19/scopes-in-rails-3/) the query.

In Rails 3, this would look something like

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :involving, lambda do |user|
    joins(:messages)
      .where("conversations.user_id = ?", user.id)
      .where("conversations.interlocutor_id = ?", user.id)
      .order("messages.created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

Use it like this:

```
Conversation.involving(me).all
```

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't a `User` have many `Conversations`? That makes the most sense to me...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :conversations
end
```

Additionally, you *already said* that a `Conversation` `belongs_to` a `User`! You didn't complete the other half of the relationship...

Comment: foreign_key of conversations can be user_id or interlocutor_id (user_id is id of user, who have started the conversation, interlocutor_id is id of conversation`s interlocutor). So I need to merge all conversations of user (it means that in result no matter who have started the conversation).

Comment: hmm.. also I didn't sure that I've correctly translated word "interlocutor" from my first language. It means "the another member of conversation" :)